# On the number of $2 \times 2$ matrices over ${\Bbb Z}_3$ with unit determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, finite-fields

> Determine the number of matrices in ${\Bbb Z}_3^{2 \times 2}$ with determinant $1$.

---

I know that the elements in ${\Bbb Z}_3$ are $\{0,1,2\}$ now possibly determinant can be $1$ in this case

$$
\begin
{bmatrix}
1&2\\
0&1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and there can be many more but how to find the exact number of such matrices? I know that the answer is $24$.

Answer (score 6):

First we count the non-singular $2\times 2$ matrices. The first row can be any of the $8$ non-zero vectors. Then the second row can be anything but a multiple of the first row. There are $3$ such multiples. Thus there are $(8)(6)$ non-singular $2\times 2$ matrices.

Mutiplying a row by $2$ multiplies the determinant by $2$, giving a bijection between matrices with determinant $1$ and those with determinant $2$. So there are $24$ with determinant $1$.

**Remark:** The idea generalizes to larger matrices, and other finite fields.

Comment: I do not understand this in your explanation "giving a bijection between matrices with determinant 1 and those with determinant  2 " what bijection is there?

Comment: Call two non-singular matrices **friends** if their second rows are the same, and the first row of one is obtained by multiplying the first row of the other by $2$. (Note that $2*2=1$.)  Our $48$ matrices are divided this way into $24$ groups of $2$ friends. If you multiply the first row of a matrix by $2$, you multiply its determinant by $2$ (modulo $3$). So if one of a pair of friends has determinant $1$, the other has determinant $2$, and vice versa. Thus each group of $2$ friends has one member of det. $1$ and one of det. $2$. So there are $24$ of each kind.

Comment: Thanks sir for your reply and explanation I understand this, but if you don't mind please tell me how do you 8*6=48 non singular matrices, I mean you said there are 3 such multiples may be you mean 0,1,2 but we can not multiply the second row with 0, as determinant will be 0. Remaining 2 multiples but still how we can get 8*6 such nonsingular matrices. Please reply thank you

Comment: We can choose the first row in $3^2-1$ ways.  For any  particular first row $v$, the only forbidden second rows are $(0)v$, $(1)v$, and $(2)V$. So for every legal first row, there are $3^2-3$ good second rows. Total $(3^2-1)(3^2-3)=48$.

Comment: Thanks sir,  I understood it now.  You had mentioned it correctly at very first but I really didn't get it at that time. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: You are welcome. I gave the proof above mainly because it generalizes almost immediately to other finite fields, in particular $\mathbb{Z}_p$ for all primes $p$, and (after a bit of effort counting the non-singulars) to $n\times n$ matrices.

Answer (score 3):

Let your matrix be $$\pmatrix{a & b\cr c & d\cr}$$
If $b c = 0$ you want $ad = 1$.  How many possibilities for that?

If $b c = 2$ you want $ad = 0$.  How many possibilities for that?

If $b c = 1$ you want $ad = 2$.  How many possibilities for that?

Comment: if $bc=2$ and $ad=0$, I think the determinant is $-2$ and not $1$

Comment: @stity $-2 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$

Comment: ok misunderstood the question then, sorry

Answer (score -1):

Since we need determinant equal to $1$, the number of $2\times 2$ matrices over $\Bbb Z_3$ will be equal to the order of $\operatorname{SL}(2,3)$, which is $$\dfrac{(3^2-1)(3^2-3)}{3-1}=24$$
As order of SL(n,F) where F is a field such that |F|=p is equal to (p^n-1)(p^n-p)---(p^n-p^n-1)/(p-1)

Comment: Where does your formula come from?

Comment: Order of SL(n,F) where F is a field such that |F|=p is (p^n-1)(p^n-p)(p^n-p^2)-----(p^n-p^n-1)/(p-1)

Comment: I'd suggest you add this to your answer, because as it stands, the numeric expression may seem unjustified to people unfamiliar with this formula and hence attract downvotes, even though I didn't -1.